# Link multiple cells from Excel to Word without inserting line break

Tags: excel, ms-word, hyperlink, ms-office

I have a Word doc in which I'm inserting links to an Excel file. For single Excel cells I can use `Paste Special>Paste Link>Unformatted Text` to link to just the cell contents. However, sometimes I want to link multiple cells laid out as a table in Word.

If I copy the cell range I want and then use `Paste>Link & Use Destination Styles` or `Paste>Link & Keep Source Formatting`, a line break gets inserted above the table, which I do not want but can't get rid of as it's part of the linked field. If I use the unformatted text option, I lose the basic table layout. None of the `Paste Special` options seem to work for this.

The only workaround I can think of is to link as unformatted text each cell in the table individually, but with sometimes hundreds of cells, that's not really an option. Help! What can I do?

(One reason I am having trouble with the line break above is that I'm trying to use `Insert Caption` with the tables thus linked, but when I do, the resultant caption gets incorporated into the linked field, and so when I update fields, the caption disappears since it's not in Excel... workarounds for that would help too.)

I am using Microsoft Office Professional Plus 2016.

[EDIT: Example here!]
Word doc:

[image]

Linked Excel sheet (Cells A1:C3):

[image]

If I highlight some or all of the table and `Update Link`, the caption disappears:

[image]

And when my cursor is at the line break above the table, the table fields highlight as that line break is somehow considered part of the linked field:

[image]

Comment: You are unlikely to get answers here because your question is off-topic for this forum. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic This forum is about programming, not about how to use applications like Word. You would have better luck with Super User https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-word or the Word Answers Forum. http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word?sort=lastreplydate&dir=desc&tab=threads&status=all&mod=&modAge=&advFil=&postedAfter=&postedBefore=&threadType=all&tm=1473637240674

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to add a space before the line break to make sure the caption is not within the linked field. Look at difference between the two example below:

- Cursor is now placed just before the line break. The values are highlighted, indicating that the linked field is selected:

[image]

- Now there's a space between the cursor and the line break. The values are not highlighted, so you can safely insert a captino here:

[image]

Comment: Huh, weird, @Lena it sounds like you're managing to do exactly what I'm having a problem with. Which paste/linking option did you go with? I will create an example and add it in a minute!

Comment: I used "Paste Special" -> "Paste link" -> Formatted Text (RTF)

Comment: I updated my answer based on your example.